# php sending array from an input value through ajax

Tags: php, jquery

I'm saving an array like this

```
<input type="hidden" value="Array ( [0] => cb_05 [1] => cb_06 [2] => cb_07 [3] => cb_08 [4] => cb_09 [5] => type ) " id="price_id" name="price_id">
```

I need to grab the array and send it through a post in jquery

```
var price_id = $("#price_id").val();

$.post("class.php",{price_id:price_id},function(data){


        alert(data);


    });
```

When I do foreach in the class it doesn't see it as an array, I think it's because it's being sent as a string, is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `data-` attribute and jQuery `data()` method to work with array

```
<anyElement id="price_id" data-priceArray="<?php echo json_encode($array) ?>"/>
<!-- will look like-->
<anyElement id="price_id" data-priceArray="["1","2","3","4"]"/>
```

JS

```
var price_id = $("#price_id").data('priceArray');
/* is now a js array*/
  alert(price_id[3])

$.post("class.php",{price_id:price_id},function(data){
        alert(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

php doesn't automatically recognize a string that came from print_r() as being an array. You need to use specific functions to serialize the array into something php can recognize. `json_encode()` is a good function to use for that.

But, `json_encode()` may produce a string that will have quotes and other characters in it that will break your html, so we need to encode it one more time with an encoding that is free of such characters. we use `base64_encode()` for that.

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?=base64_encode(json_encode($source_array))?>" id="price_id" name="price_id">
```

later, when you receive the ajax or form post

```
$reified_array = json_decode(base64_decode($_POST['price_id']));
foreach ($reified_array as $val) { ... }
```

[json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)
[json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)
[base64_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php)